# How to disable the background when sidebar is shown and clicking on the anywhere except sidebar will close the sidebar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sidebar

I am making a sidebar for my website.

1. When my sidebar appears (showRight is clicked) I want to disable the background content so the user cannot do anything outside of the menu.
2. When the user clicks the background the sidebar will disappeared and then they will get the access to the background content again. Right now I am closing the sidebar when the hide button is clicked.

Can anyone help me out?

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    .cbp-spmenu {
      background: #fff;
      position: fixed;
    }

    .cbp-spmenu-vertical {
      width: 400px;
      height: 100%;
      top: 0;
      z-index: 1000;
    }

    .cbp-spmenu-right {
      right: -400px;
    }

    .cbp-spmenu, #cbp-spmenu-push {
      -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
      -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
      transition: all 0.3s ease;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="menu">
    <span class="cbp-spmenu cbp-spmenu-vertical cbp-spmenu-right" id="cbp-spmenu-s1">
      <h4>Avinash</h4>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <section id="about">
      <button id="showRight">Show</button>
      <button id="showRight2">Hide</button>
    </section>
    <script>
      var menuRight = document.getElementById( 'cbp-spmenu-s1' ),
          showRight = document.getElementById( 'showRight' ),
          showRight2 = document.getElementById( 'showRight2' ),
          content = document.getElementById( 'avi' ),
          menu = document.getElementById( 'menu' ),
          body = document.body;

      showRight.onclick = function() {
        classie.add(this,"active");
        menuRight.style.right = '0px';
        content.style.opacity = '0.5';
        body.style.display = 'block';
      };

      showRight2.onclick = function() {
        if (classie.has(showRight,"active")) {
          menuRight.style.right = '-400px';
          classie.remove(showRight,"active");
          content.style.opacity = '1';
        } 
      };
    </script>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you can create a div that covers the whole site except for the sidebar

put this div right after your body tag like so:

```
<div class="overlay"></div>
```

in your css:

```
body{
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.overlay{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5000px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Then use your javascript to change the `z-index` value of that div to 9999 or whatever covers everything.

**update: Set your sidebar z-index in css to something higher than this new value**

Might not be ideal but consider it if you don't get any better answers.

Comment: The z-index needs to be in between sidebar + content, not over everything :p except that, this solution will do

Comment: Since my sidebar has `z-index:1000` I am changing the `z-index` of the `div  overlay` to `999` through javascript but now the sidebar is not appearing.      `overlay.onclick = function(){
                overlay.style.z-index = "999";
            }` but when i remove the javascript function of onclick it is appearing normally.

Answer (score 0):

You should to add overlay block.

```
<div class="overlay"></div>

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 999; /* sidebar must have z-index > 999 */
  background: white;
  opacity: 0; /* or background set to rgba(255, 255, 255, 0); */
}
```